# Can't install npm pkg on Apple M1 node-pre-gyp error

Tags: node.js, node-pre-gyp

I wanted to install the [tiktok-scraper](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper) through node. For this I downgraded node from version 18 to 16, but the packages Installation still won't work.

I was getting the following error:

```
user@xxx ~ % npm i -g tiktok-scraper
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.6: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.1 and node@16.15.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.1/canvas-v2.9.1-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.12 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/sablowskin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/sablowskin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pangocairo' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@16/16.15.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/tiktok-scraper/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried all the possible solution tasks I found. Please, help me solve this bug.
From npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org and other many other possibilities. This Laptop is new so there may are missing dependencies. I have tried to install them but got the same error with pkg canvas.